# Did you get any good out of collaborative editors usage?

Tags: networking, editor, collaboration

today I was looking for a free collaborative code editor for Mac OS X, I don't really need it but I find the idea pretty charming. So I want to know you opinion about that: is there someone in real world who is using a collaborative code editor and gets some benefits out of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use it over the Internet when discussing code via Chat/VoIP. Something along:

A: "If we change this to be an Integer the function gets much simpler" (Edit)

B: "Niftiy, but then we have to change it here, too" (Edit)

A: ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're pairs programming it is very useful. The approach can be discussed and everyone can drive when they have ideas. I can't say I've had the privilege of using this at work.

Comment: I would say if you are using two computers for pair-programming you aren't pair-programming.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it fairly useful when putting together packing/todo/etc lists with my wife while at work.  We use google docs, which isn't quite realtime, but it is definitely better than emailing back and forth throughout the day.